# Classification of groups of order $2p^3$ and $2p^4$.

Tags: finite-groups, group-extensions

Where can I find these two result? And how to charicterize $Z_2$-extension of an Abelian group? If not, can we conunt the number of $Z_2$-extension of an Abelian group? Thank you for your help!

Comment: So I assume you have already classified groups of order $p^3$ and $p^4$?

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/64429/11619) to a link classifying groups of order $p^3$. A group of order $2p^3$ is a semi-direct product of its unique Sylow $p$-subgroup and $C_2$, so you need to classify the automorphisms of order at most two as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact, I want to know how to count the total number of $Z_2$-extension of an abelian group. Is there some result? Or do you know how to proof?