# Number of non-isomorphic group of order 8?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Number of non-isomorphic group of order 8 ?

1. 2
2. 3
3. 4
4. 5

I have no clue how to solve this. It's a group of order $p^3$ so is there any general way to calculate the number of non-isomorphic groups of such orders?

Comment: If you can do the abelian case (by the fundamental theorem), then look at this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64406/how-can-you-show-there-are-only-2-nonabelian-groups-of-order-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For abelian groups use Structure theorem for finitely generated abelian groups groups.

For non abelian Groups:

**Hint:** As $G$ is a $p$-group so $Z(G)$ can not be trivial and $\frac {G}{Z(G)}$ can not be cyclic because $G$ is nonabelian.Therefore order$(Z(G))=2$ and hence $ \frac {G}{Z(G)} \cong \frac { \mathbb Z}{2\mathbb Z } \times  \frac { \mathbb Z}{2\mathbb Z }$.Now proceed...

**Conclusion:** There are $5$ groups of order $8$ in which $3$ are abelian and $2$ are nonabelian.

Comment: so the answer to the question is $5$ right? As the groups are $\mathbb{Z_8}$, $\mathbb{Z_4\times Z_2}$, $\mathbb{Z_2\times Z_2\times Z_2}$ and $D_4$, quaternions.

Comment: Dear @HarryPotter: You're absolutely right!