# If a group has order $100$ and every subgroup of $G$ is normal why can't it be non-abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I've read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_group) that such a group has the form $Q_8 \times B \times D$, so my question really is why can't $G$ be direct product like this? Also, I'd like to know what happens if $|G|=200$?

Comment: Because $100$ isn't divisible by $8$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all subgroups are normal, the Sylow subgroups are unique and $G=HK$ for a $2$-Sylow $H$ and a $5$-Sylow $K$ which centralize each other.  They are both of square prime order, so they are both Abelian, and thus $G$ is Abelian.

If $|G|=200$ it is no longer certain the Sylows are Abelian. You could have a $2$-Sylow that looks like the quaternion group.

Comment: Is it possible that when the group $G$ of order $200$ is nilpotent then every subgroup of $G$  is normal?

Comment: @user264885 Isn't $C_8\oplus C_{25}$ a counterexample? I'm not 100% sure.. I was just looking for groups that weren't of the Hamiltonian form you mentioned. The $2$-sylow doesn't seem to fit the description.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I will check if that is true.

Comment: @user264885 Sorry no, I didn't realize Hamiltonian groups are defined to be nonabelian. My example is not a counterexample.

Comment: @user264885 There is another [nonabelian group of order 8](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/64406/29335) it looks like. I think if you use that with $C_{25}$, you have a counterexample.

Answer (score 6):

$G$ has normal  subgroups of order $4$ and $25$ respectively say $H,K$.

Then $G$ is direct product of $H$ and $K$ since $\gcd(o(H),o(K))=1$

Since every   group of order $p^2$  is abelian so are $H,K$ and hence so is $G$