# Show that a non-abelian group of order 8 with a single element of order 2 is isomorphic to Q group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, quaternions

where Q is the quaternion group. Thanks !

Here are my thoughts : 
With the Lagrange's theorem, we have that the order of the subgroup divides the order of the group. But there is a single element that has order 2 (b for example), thus you have that there exists a unique subgroup of order 4 generated by a (but is it stated without proof because it's straightforward?) and thus you have that b^2 = a^2 because b is the only element that has order 2. And i don't know how to proof that aba = b

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: See Jyrki's answer at [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64406/how-can-you-show-there-are-only-2-nonabelian-groups-of-order-8).

Comment: Excuse me but i don't understand how to proof that a group of order 8 with a subgroup maximum order that equals to 4  is normal..