# Non cyclic group of order $p^3$ satisfies $G \simeq H \rtimes_{\theta}K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, semidirect-product

Let $G$ be a non-cyclic group of order $p^3$ for an odd prime $p$. Prove that $G \simeq H \rtimes_{\theta}K$, where $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ of order $p^2$, $K$ is a subgroup of order $p$, and $\theta : K \to Aut(H)$ is a homomorphism.

---

I managed to prove that there exists a normal subgroup $H$ of order $p^2$. Then I took some $g \in G-H$. If $g$ is of order $p$, I am done since $G \simeq H \rtimes \langle g \rangle $. But what if all $g \in G - H$ are of order $p^2 $?

Comment: Impossible that all the non-trivial elements in $\;G\;$ are of order $\;p^2\;$ since there exists a subgroup of order $\;p\;$ ...

Comment: Sorry, I meant all $g \in G - H$. I edited my question

Comment: Observe that the conclusion would be false when $p=2$. The quaternion group $Q_8$. In other words, the fact that $p$ is odd must come into play somehow.

Comment: The claim seems to follow from the observations made by the OP and the argument given in [this old answer by Arturo Magidin](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/64555/11619).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result follows immediately if all elements of $G$ have order $1$ or $p$, so we can assume that there exists an element of order $p^2$. This generates a cyclic subgroup of index $p$, which is normal in $G$, so we can assume that $H$ is cyclic of order $p^2$.

So let $g \in G \setminus H$, and assume that $g$ has order $p^2$ (if it has order $p$ then we are done). So $g^p = h^p$ for some $h \in H$. We claim that $(gh^{-1})^p=1$, and hence $gh^{-1}$ has order $p$ and we are done.

This is immediate if $G$ is abelian, so suppose not. Then $[G,G]=Z(G)$ has order $p$, so commutators are central, and $(xy^{-1})^p = x^py^{-p}[y^{-1},x]^{p(p-1)/2}$ (where $[a,b]$ denotes the commutator $a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$).

Then, since $p$ is odd and $[y^{-1},x]$ has order $p$, we get $[y^{-1},x]^{p(p-1)/2}=1$ and the claim follows. (Note that this result is false when $p=2$, and the quaternion group $Q_8$ is a counterexample.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please explain why $(xy^{-1})^p=x^py^{-p}[y^{-1},x]^{p(p-1)/2}$ ?

Comment: If $[G,G] \le Z(G)$ then $(ab)^k = a^kb^k[b,a]^{k(k-1)/2}$ for all $a,b \in G$ and all $k \ge 0$. Prove it by induction on $k$, using $ba = ab[b,a]$.

Comment: Where did you use the fact that $H$ is cyclic?

Comment: The existence of $h \in H$ such that $g^p=h^p$.