# Exercises about Galois theory and isomorphism type of the Galois-Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

I have this two exercise where I have some problems:

(a) We consider the finite field extension $E := \mathbb{Q}( \sqrt[4]{2}, i)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Show that $E$ is a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ and determine the isomorphism type of the Galois group $G := Gal(E/ \mathbb{Q})$.

(b) For each subgroup $H ≤ G$, determine the field extension $Q ⊆ L ⊆ E$ corresponding to the main theorem of Galois theory. For which of these intermediate fields $L$, is $L$ a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$?

So for a) I have that since the finite  extension field is normal and separable we have a Galois extension field.

For the isomorphism type I need to find $Gal(E/ \mathbb{Q})$ first.
I hope it is clear that $[\mathbb{Q}( \sqrt[4]{2}, i):\mathbb{Q}]=8$. So if we find 8 $E$-Automorphisms over $\mathbb{Q}$ we have found our $Gal(E/ \mathbb{Q})$.

The 8 Automorphisms that I have in mind are

$\tau_1:\left\{\begin{matrix} \sqrt[4]{2} \rightarrow \sqrt[4]{2}\\ i \rightarrow i \end{matrix}\right. , \tau_2:\left\{\begin{matrix} \sqrt[4]{2} \rightarrow \sqrt[4]{2}\\ i \rightarrow -i \end{matrix}\right.,\\\tau_3:\left\{\begin{matrix} \sqrt[4]{2} \rightarrow -\sqrt[4]{2}\\ i \rightarrow i \end{matrix}\right.,\tau_4:\left\{\begin{matrix} \sqrt[4]{2} \rightarrow -\sqrt[4]{2}\\ i \rightarrow -i \end{matrix}\right., \\ \tau_5:\left\{\begin{matrix} \sqrt[4]{2} \rightarrow i\sqrt[4]{2}\\ i \rightarrow i \end{matrix}\right.,\tau_6:\left\{\begin{matrix} \sqrt[4]{2} \rightarrow -i\sqrt[4]{2}\\ i \rightarrow i \end{matrix}\right.,\\ \tau_7:\left\{\begin{matrix} \sqrt[4]{2} \rightarrow i\sqrt[4]{2}\\ i \rightarrow -i \end{matrix}\right.,\tau_8:\left\{\begin{matrix} \sqrt[4]{2} \rightarrow -i\sqrt[4]{2}\\ i \rightarrow -i \end{matrix}\right.$

Therefore we have that $G =\{id,\tau_2,\tau_3,\tau_4,\tau_5,\tau_6,\tau_7,\tau_8 \}$.
So now I had in mind to check the order of this 8 Automorphisms  to obtain the isomorphism type.
for $\tau_2, \tau_3, \tau_4$ I have order $2$ but for $\tau_5,\tau_6,\tau_7,\tau_8$ I dont know how to find the order. Can someone help me? Even once I found the order of the other 4, I wouldn't know how to find the type of isomorphy. could someone help me?

While for b) I think (Sorry for the confusion but I am new to the Galois theory)I have to take some of the automorphisms of $G$ and from them I have to obtain the intermediate fields but here too I don't know how to do it.

Comment: In order to understand the isomorphism type, it's not always necessary to compute the group itself. For example, without any computations one can see that this group has a non-normal subgroup (why?), and if you know the classification of groups of order $8$, that immediately gives you the answer.

Comment: One way forward. A) Show that the group is not abelian. B) Determine which it is. [This admittedly a bit silly old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/64419/11619) points at a way. Basically you should count the number of elements of order four :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen It's actually even easier. Only one group of order $8$ has non normal subgroups.

Comment: True, @Mark. And only one of them can be realized as a group permuting the four roots :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen sorry I corrected the table

Comment: Can you show that the squares of both $\tau_5$ and $\tau_6$ are equal to $\tau_3$? Hence they have order four.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, thanks. But after that how can I find the isomorphism type with these informations?

Comment: A non-abelian group of order $8$ is either $Q_8$ or $D_4$. The former has only a single element of order two. Furthermore, it is not a subgroup of $S_4$ (which is what you know this group to be, if you are familiar with the realization of the Galois group of a splitting field as a permutation of roots).