# Non-Boolean group with every element of order two

Tags: abelian-groups, boolean-algebra

Let $G$ be a group (not necessarily finite) such every element of $G$ has order 2. Every such group is abelian [[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17054/group-where-every-element-is-order-2)].

Clearly, every Boolean algebra $B$ is a group of this type,
when equipped with the symmetric difference operation.

**Question**: is there any group $G$ such that there does not exist a Boolean algebra $B$ equipped with the symmetric difference such that $B$ is isomorphic to $G$?

**EDIT:** It is clear to me, that every such group must be a direct sum of
$\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$. This suggests a counterexample: take a countably infinite direct sum of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$. Clearly, we can model this group by all
finite subsets of $\mathbb N$ equipped with symmetric difference, and this is
not a Boolean algebra. But there is a mistake in this reasoning; the set system of question is not a Boolean algebra *as a set system*. It can still be a Boolean algebra *as an abelian group*.

Or not?

Answer (score 3):

Write $G$ as a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ over some index set $X \cup \{e\}$. Then it is isomorphic as an abelian group to the Boolean algebra of all finite *or cofinite* subsets of $X$ (where the presence or absence of the basis element corresponding to $e$ tells you whether a given element of $G$ corresponds to a finite or cofinite subset).

Comment: Signed (very) long int, eh? I like it.