# Term for a group where every element is its own inverse?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology

Several groups have the property that every element is its own inverse.  For example, the numbers $0$ and $1$ and the XOR operator form a group of this sort, and more generally the set of all bitstrings of length $n$ and XOR form a group with this property.

These groups have the interesting property that [they have to be commutative](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/17057/8955).

Is there a special name associated with groups with this property?  Or are they just "abelian groups where every element has order two?"

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are often called [Boolean groups](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition%3aBoolean_Group).

Answer (score 9):

Another term for these groups is elementary abelian $2$-groups. In general, an elementary abelian $p$-group (for a prime $p$) is an abelian group where every non-identity element has order $p$ (and it is easy to see that if all non-identity elements have the same order, then that order must be a prime).

Comment: Be careful though, because the word "2-group" can have a [completely different meaning](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-group)...

Comment: @MonstrousMoonshiner I would rather say that anyone wanting to use the term for the higher categorical stuff needs to make sure not to cause confusion, seeing as they could easily have chosen so many other names for it (or at least added an "oid" or something).

Answer (score 5):

These are (the underlying additive groups of) the vector spaces over $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

Another term is "group of exponent $2$".