# Are groups satisfying $g=g^{-1}$ for all $g \in G$ abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Is the following statement true or false:
>
> > If $G$ is a group with the property that $g=g^{-1}$ for all $g \in G$, then $G$ is abelian.

I believe it is false since I know that abelian or commutative property implies that every element in $G$ must have an inverse. Thus $g\cdot g^{-1}= g^{1}\cdot g = e$.

I need someone to check my attempt.

Comment: I did not understand **i know that abelian or commutative property implies that every element in G must have an inverse. Thus g.g^(-1)= g^(1).g = e**

Comment: Hint:  If $G$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian.  Now, what do you know about cyclic groups?

Comment: Not clear how your attempt is meant to work. You need to _prove_ that the group (you know it is a group, so you know inverses exist) is abelian. Or else, you need to come up with an _example_ where $g=g^{-1}$ for all $g$ and the group is not abelian. Which one did you attempt?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik That is my attempt but i want comments on the attempt and if the attempt i need know if am on the right track or not.

Comment: your attempted proof is not a proof at all. First, the statement is true. Second, that there exists an nverse (which in fact is *unique*) for any element in the group is one of the axioms of group theory and thus true for **any** group, abelian or not.

Comment: @Lynnie : I am saying that i did not understand your attempt...

Comment: See also [Group where every element is order 2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17054/) and the threads linked to it.

Comment: @Timbuc thanks thats clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Suppose that $g=g^{-1}, \forall g \in G$. Then*

*$g.g=g.g^{-1}=e\implies g^2=e.$*

*So for $x,y\in G, (xy)(xy)=e$.*

*$\therefore xy=(xe)y=x(xy.xy)y=(xx)yx(yy)=yx$.*

*Hence G is abelian.* $\blacksquare$

Comment: Hi can you explain this g.g=g.g^(−1)=e⟹g^(2)=e.

Comment: **Axiom 4 :** *$\exists$ unique $a^{-1}\in G$ such that $a.a^{-1}=a^{-1}.a=e$. Here considering step 1 and multiply both sides by g gives LHS as $g^2$ and RHS as $e$.*

Answer (score 4):

Your attempt is not valid.  You have stated the axioms of inverses for groups, but these have nothing to do with whether the group is abelian or not.  The question is when every element *is its own inverse*, which happens only rarely.

If $G$ is a group such that $g^{-1}=g$ for all $g\in G$, how can we show that any two elements of $G$ commute?  If $x,y\in G$, what happens if we set $g=xy$?

Comment: Further hint: $xy = (xy)^{-1} = \dots = yx$.

Answer (score 2):

Hints for you to understand and prove:

== In any group, $\;(gh)^{-1}=h^{-1}g^{-1}\;$ :

== A group is abelian iff $\;\forall\;g,h\in G\;,\;\;gh=hg\iff\;(hg)^{-1}gh=1\;$