# Prove that a group $G$ is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Suppose we have a group $(G, *).$ Prove that the group is abelian if $b * a^2 = b$ where $(a, b)$ are part of the group.

Comment: What do you mean by $(a,b)$ are part of the group? Do you mean that $a,b \in G$

Comment: this is not clear.  Are you saying this should hold for all $a,b\in G$?  That only works if every element of $G$ has order $2$.  Is that what you intended?

Comment: @AnuragA yes that is what I wanted to write

Comment: Once you cancel the $b$, you get $a^2=1$ for every $a$. Proving that this is abelian is a standard question, see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17054/group-where-every-element-is-order-2

Comment: There are a couple ways but you should have already proven that inverses are unique and cancelation laws hold so $a^2*b = b$ means $a^2 = e$ and $a=a^{-1}$. and from ther $(ab)(ba) = ab^2a = a^2 =e$ so $ba = (ab)^{-1} = ab$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the associative property to write

\begin{align*}
ab &= (b^2a)(a^2b) \\
&= b(ba^2)ab \\
&= (ba)(ab) \\
&= b(a^2b) \\
&= ba.
\end{align*}

Hence $G$ is Abelian.