# Infinite group whose every element is of order $4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, infinite-groups

I have constructed infinite group whose every element is of prime order by taking the set as set  of sequences whose elements are from integers modulo $p$ and operation is integers modulo $p$.

Now ***how can I get an infinite group whose every element is of order $4$ (non prime) except identity?***.

Is there any general way of finding an infinite group whose every element is of order $n$?

Comment: The square of an order $4$ element has order $2$.

Comment: In what group? You are taking?

Comment: [Related.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/17054/104041)

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: You can't do such for a non prime order.  If $n = jk$ then if $|a| = jk$ then $(a^j)^k= e$ and $|a^j| \le k$.

Comment: You couldn’t possibly have constructed a group in which every element has prime order, because in every group there is always an element of order $1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $\lvert a\rvert=4$ for some $a\in G$ for some group $G$. Then $(a^2)^2=e$ and $a^2$ is non-trivial, so  $$\lvert a^2\rvert=2.$$

Comment: I didn't understand, do you got the question correctly,? I may not be clear in my question?  We need to find a group whose every element is of order 4?

Comment: Yes, @Mr.Multitalented, but if an element, any element, of a group, any group, has order four, then its square has order two, as proven above; thus no group exists in which every element has order four.

Comment: @mr.multitalented this answer is telling you that it’s imposible find the group you’re looking for.

Comment: Okay.. Got it.. Thank you 